# Loop through an array within an array php to get values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array inside an array and I want to loop through the array to get the values so I can store them in a database. What would be the best way to approach this in PHP?

The array:

```
Array
(
    [instrument] => AUD_CAD
    [granularity] => H1
    [candles] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [complete] => 1
                [volume] => 942
                [time] => 2018-06-03T21:00:00.000000000Z
                [bid] => Array
                    (
                        [o] => 0.97957
                        [h] => 0.98054
                        [l] => 0.97957
                        [c] => 0.98048
                    )

                [mid] => Array
                    (
                        [o] => 0.98032
                        [h] => 0.98083
                        [l] => 0.98022
                        [c] => 0.98076
                    )

                [ask] => Array
                    (
                        [o] => 0.98107
                        [h] => 0.98133
                        [l] => 0.98050
                        [c] => 0.98105
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [complete] => 1
                [volume] => 888
                [time] => 2018-06-03T22:00:00.000000000Z
                [bid] => Array
                    (
                        [o] => 0.98048
                        [h] => 0.98069
                        [l] => 0.97972
                        [c] => 0.97986
                    )

                [mid] => Array
                    (
                        [o] => 0.98077
                        [h] => 0.98093
                        [l] => 0.97989
                        [c] => 0.97998
                    )

                [ask] => Array
                    (
                        [o] => 0.98106
                        [h] => 0.98124
                        [l] => 0.98000
                        [c] => 0.98011
                    )

            )
    )
)
```

I wish to get the values like so:

```
foreach ($get_instruments_candles['candles'] as $candle) {
    // first array part
    $instrument = $candle['instrument'];
    $granularity = $candle['granularity'];

    // one level deeper into the array
    $complete = $candle[0]['complete'];
    $volume = $candle[0]['volume'];

    //another level deeper
    $open = $candle[0]['mid']['o'];
    $high = $candle[0]['mid']['h'];
    $low = $candle[0]['mid']['l'];
    $close = $candle[0]['mid']['c'];

    // check if exists in db
    // do a check here or insert data
    echo 'insert in db  ins= '. $instrument. ' gran='. $granularity .' com= '. $complete .' open =' .$open. ' high = ' . $high . ' low = ' . $low . ' close = ' . $close;
 }
```

This array can contain say 500 [candles] 0,1,2,3 - 500 etc I want to store the values into variables so I can do a check on my database to check if exists or then use the values for a database insert for each specific [candles] array values. `time`, `o`, `h`, `l` and `c` being the important parts of the data.

Comment: Excellent example with code. But what is the question?

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? PDO or MySQLi?

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  However, you are referencing some of your array indexes incorrectly.

Lets break this down into two parts.  First lets just condense your data into a nice array that you can later use for your queries.

Step 1:

```
foreach ($get_instruments_candles['candles'] as $candle) {

    //Create an array containing just the information that you want for each item.
    $newArray[] = array(

      'ins'     => $get_instruments_candles['instrument'],
      'gran'    => $get_instruments_candles['granularity'],
      'com'     => $candle['complete'],
      'volume'  => $candle['volume'],
      'open'    => $candle['mid']['o'],
      'high'    => $candle['mid']['h'],
      'low'     => $candle['mid']['l'],
      'close'   => $candle['mid']['c']

    ); 

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Now you have an array containing just the information you want for each item.

Step 2:

You will need to be able have a valid connection to a database and know your table and column names.  But here is an example of how you would use the newly created array to perform your queries.

```
//Here is an example of an parameterized insert query.
$query = "INSERT INTO YOURTABLE 
(
  ins,
  gran,
  com,
  volume,
  open,
  high,
  low,
  close
) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";


//Use a loop and iterate across your items and execute your query for each item.
foreach($newArray as $item){

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', ...$item);
$stmt->execute();    

}

$stmt->close();
```

If you are new to parameterized queries you should read this link.

[MySQLi Parameterized Queries](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

They also have one for PDO

[PDO Parameterized Queries](https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Bookmark these and refer to them often.  They will also show you how to set up your DB connections properly.

Hope this helps.